# How do you remove rows off of a dataframe based off of a list of index values?

Tags: r, shiny

Basically, I have an input that needs to be processed and I can't seem to figure out how to remove rows based on a list of indexes I have.

````
```warmup_index <- c()
for(i in 1:length(wbb1$Power)) {
  if (wbb1$Power[i] < 10) {
    warmup_index <- c(warmup_index, i)
  }
  else {
    next
  }
}

# Removes from Dataframe
for(i in 1:length(warmup_index)) {
  wbb1 <- wbb1[-c(warmup_index[i]),]
}```
````

Using this method, it removes like every other row because the file is constantly updating. Is there a way to remove all of the indexes in the list at once without having that problem?

Answer (score 1):

We don't need a loop here, i.e. either use `which` to get the position index from the logical vector and remove the rows with `-`

```
warmup_index <- which(wbb1$Power < 10)
wbb1 <- wbb1[-warmup_index,]
```

---

Or we directly use the logical vector and negate (`!`)

```
wbb1<- wbb1[!wbb1$Power < 10,]
```

Or change the logic to `>=`  to keep the rows (avoids the extra negation)

```
wbb1 <- wbb1[wbb1$Power > 10,]
```